# How to pin a note in Tomboy app indicator?

Tags: 11.10, indicator, tomboy

Is there a way to pin some notes in Tomboy's app indicator so that I don't have to open the main window every time I'm looking for one specific note I read regularly? 
It used to work before Unity because it wasn't an app indicator but a panel applet.

Do I have to install some package or file a bug?

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be a limitation of Appindicator.

See [Launchpad bug #738200](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomboy/+bug/738200).

> in previous ubuntu version there was a pin icon by each note in the
>   drop down menu. clicking it would pin that note into the menu.

and

> Yup, this is a bug with ubuntu's appindicator patch. Last time I
>   checked the appindicator infrastructure did not have support for
>   pinned items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll wait until this bug is resolved then.

Comment: @user21088: You should mark lgarzo's answer as accepted, then. ;-)